# DAX Calculate Measure unaffected by row in table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new in DAX and I'm having some trouble calculating a value that must be similar in all the rows independently of the row. I'll explain in more detail:

I have to calculate the adoption of certain use of a program:

```
Sales in Program/Total Sales
```

(This only includes customers that have access to the program. Total sales might include sales performed by the program or not)

Some customer are not onboarded in this program and I would like to calculate the impact of onboarding this customer into the program:

```
 # of Sales in Program/# of Total Sales - # of Sales in Program/(# of Total Sales + # of Customer sales)
```

The # of customer sales is of course outside the program. The adoption calculation (# of Sales in Program/# of Total Sales) must be the same for all customers, the only data that changes according to the row is # of Customer sales. My data is transactional and is like this:

```
Customer Order    Date        Onboarded  Program
01       001      01-01-2018  Yes        In Program
01       002      01-01-2018  Yes        Not In Program
03       003      01-01-2018  No         In Program
```

So far, I have:

```
Adoption = CALCULATE(  COUNT(Adoption[Order]), 
                       FILTER(Adoption, Adoption[Program] = "In Program" &&
                                        Adoption[Onboarded] = "Yes")
            /
            CALCULATE(  COUNT(Adoption[Order])
                       FILTER(Adoption, Adoption[Onboarded] = "Yes"))
```

I tried to use `All` but still it was affected by the rows. How can I make it so that the adoption is the same for all the rows?

So far, my output is something like this (note: right now I'm just calculating the first part of the equation):

```
Customer  Adoption
01        0.5
02        0.2
03        0.7
```

However, it should be the same for all:

```
Customer  Adoption
01        0.4
02        0.4
03        0.4
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us what values you are getting and what values you expect to get?

Comment: @AlexisOlson Yes, I just updated the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't duplicate your values and your `Adoption` measure appears to be missing a `)` and a `,` at the end of the 3rd and 5th lines respectively.

However, if you want to use `ALL` here, then it needs to go *inside* the `FILTER` function like this:

```
Adoption =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Adoption[Order] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Adoption ),
        Adoption[Program] = "In Program"
            && Adoption[Onboarded] = "Yes"
    )
)
    / CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Adoption[Order] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Adoption ),
            Adoption[Onboarded] = "Yes"
        )
    )
```

The reason it doesn't work like this

```
CALCULATE(COUNT(...), ALL(Adoption), FILTER(Adoption, ...))
```

is that the arguments of `CALCULATE` are combined using AND logic and the `FILTER` function is already a proper subset of `ALL(Adoption)` since the table passed as the first argument is *already evaluated within the local filter context*. That is, the `Customer` number is a filter on that table unless you remove it. In order to remove that filter context, you need to apply `ALL` at that level instead of trying to combine it after you've done your filtering.

Comment: Thanks so much Alexis!! This is exactly what I needed to calculate the first part. For the second part I just added to the denominator count of orders.